# Windows filesystem operations become unreliable under load

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

I work on a relatively large C++ Windows application. When running multiple instances of the application in parallel (with 100% CPU usage), for example during execution of our test suite, several file related operations start failing randomly. Some examples include:

- extracting a zip archive and the loading one of the extracted files
- writing / copying a bunch of files  and then adding them all to a zip archive
- reading files that were just written by a child process

I have read that filesystem operations aren't guaranteed to be immediately visible upon closing a file handle, so I have created a little helper function that waits until a specified file becomes accessible and littered it about the code at some of the points where I noticed the failures, but:

1. It doesn't seem to be 100% reliable
2. It feels a bit ugly, especially since I have to put it at every point where the problem might present itself

So, my question is whether anyone has any ideas for a better or more reliable solution to this or any additional insight into the problem.

Comment: Yep, it's generally just something you have to live with. Disabling AntiVirus scanning of the relevant files can help reduce the problem

Comment: Any products add a File System Filter Driver eg Virus Scanners, some games etc ?

Comment: Out of the box brainstorming: Only thing I can think of is do all file I/O based on streams which is a good idea for unit testing anyway (you can also use stringstreams instead of files during testing). And maybe there is a way to get streams to work on top of memory mapped files or pipes instead of having to rely on the files to be present on disk?

Comment: C++ was specially designed to support OOP so you do not need to copy paste same ugly code to random places all over your code base but can design classes that take the additional responsibilities and ensure the peculiarities of whatever garbage platform are taken into account and care of.

Comment: I can relate to the filesystem being unreliable. Antiviruses make things worse. Unfortunately, I know of no good solution. We also have various variants of "retry on failure" in our test system because of it.